# r shiny: updating rhandsontable from another rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, rhandsontable

I hope you're well. I am trying to create a shiny dashboard whereby a user is able to update one rhandsontable from another. My code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

channel <- c("TV","Radio","Digital")
start.date <- as.Date("2017-01-01")
end.date <- as.Date("2017-01-07")
date.range <- as.POSIXct((seq(start.date,end.date,by="day")), origin = "1970-01-01")
date.range <- as.data.frame(date.range)
colnames(date.range) <- c("date")
date.range[channel] <- 0
table1 <- date.range
table2 <- date.range
#Define the tables.

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(4, rHandsontableOutput("table1output")),
    column(4, rHandsontableOutput("table2output"))
  ))

server <- function(input,output,session){
  table <- reactiveValues()
  table$table1 <- table1
  table$table2 <- table2
  #define reactive values as table1 and table2

  output$table1output <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(table$table1)})
  output$table2output <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(table$table2)})
  #rhandsontable outputs

  observeEvent(input$table1output,{
    df <- hot_to_r(input$table1output)
    df <- as.data.frame(df)
    table$table2 <- df
  })
  #if a user updates table1 table2 should also update.

  observeEvent(input$table2output,{
    df <- hot_to_r(input$table2output)
    df <- as.data.frame(df)
    table$table1 <- df
  })
  #if a user updates table2 table1 should also update.

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Whenever I run the code i get the following errors:

```
Warning: Error in as: no method or default for coercing “character” to “NA”
```

I can't for the life of me get this to work! Any help would be very much appreciated!

Cheers,

Harry

Comment: It seems like the dates are the problem. If I replace the tables with other ones, everything works fine for me. Take a look how to use date columns in `rhandsontable`.  According to [this source](https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/), `Date` as in `Sys.Date()` is an allowed format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Allowed date formats in rhandsontable

The first problem is the format of the `date` column. It seems like `POSIXct` is not allowed here. According to [the github documentation of rhandsontable](https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/), `Date` as in `Sys.Date()` is recommended. So replacing

```
date.range <- as.POSIXct((seq(start.date,end.date,by="day")), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

with

```
date.range <- as.Date((seq(start.date,end.date,by="day")), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

solves this issue. The warning

> Warning: Error in as: no method or default for coercing “character” to “NA”

created by the call to `hot_to_r` should be gone now.

## Updating both tables at once

In order to make all changes in `table1` affect `table2` and vice versa, you can use the same reactive value to store the tables on the server side.

Here is a full working solution.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

channel <- c("TV","Radio","Digital")
start.date <- as.Date("2017-01-01")
end.date <- as.Date("2017-01-07")
date.range <- as.Date((seq(start.date,end.date,by="day")), origin = "1970-01-01")
date.range <- as.data.frame(date.range)
colnames(date.range) <- c("date")
date.range[channel] <- 0
table1 <- date.range
table2 <- date.range
#Define the tables.

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(4, rHandsontableOutput("table1output")),
    column(4, rHandsontableOutput("table2output"))
  ))

server <- function(input,output,session){
  table <- reactiveValues()
  table$table1 <- table1
  #DEFINE ONLY TABLE1

  output$table1output <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(table$table1)})
  output$table2output <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(table$table1)})
  #rhandsontable outputs

  observeEvent(input$table1output,{
    df <- hot_to_r(input$table1output)
    df <- as.data.frame(df)
    table$table1 <- df
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE, ignoreNULL = TRUE
  )
  #if a user updates table1 table2 should also update.

  observeEvent(input$table2output,{
    df <- hot_to_r(input$table2output)
    df <- as.data.frame(df)
    table$table1 <- df
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE, ignoreNULL = TRUE
  )
  #if a user updates table2 table1 should also update.

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Gregor! This worked perfectly! Such a simple error! Thanks for the example with only one reactive value too!

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your issue, please accept the answer.